# JIBX marshallar does not create empty tags for null elements

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, jibx

I have several optional fields defined in binding xml. so when I mashal java object all the optional fields having null value are not displayed in the xml.Jibx is ignoring the null values when marshalling. 
is there any way to marshal null attributes of java object marshal and display in xml?

deserialize concept will work? jaxb will work it seems, but want to know if any possiblity is there in jibx.